# Linux - how to force the operating system doesnt go into maintenance mode

Tags: linux, boot, unix

Is there any way to prevent or force a Linux System doesnt go into into maintenance mode when there is a system problem?. Example:

In this case was for file integrity.

Another opcion is if exist any method to autofix. without human interactions.

[image: example]

Comment: What do you expect to happen instead?  When you have filesystem corruption that stops the bootloader, you really do need to fix that before it boots.

Comment: ive a Novel SuSE point of service insfraestructure giving the directive RELOAD_IMAGE=yes inside KIWI config, and rebooting it will load auto the new fresh suse POS image, but for my bad i want to have more time to recover some files if is possible or the chance, and i dont want human interactions coz is more expensive, so in this case is possible to automate fsck.ext3 -y to skip human interactions and keep the SO the most time possible?.

Comment: Your request doesn't make a great deal of sense.  If you have a file integrity problem you should solve that problem, not attempt to bypass, the maintenance mode.

Comment: i want to avoid the human interaction, coz that hosts are distributed in all country and i dont want to assume the cost of technicians in all country just to type fsck -y ctrl+d, do u know any way?

Comment: I don't if or how to do it on SUSE, but on a Debian system you can auto-repair by adjusting the FSCKFIX value in `/etc/default/rcS`.